# How to give alternate prompt if input is repeatedly incorrect

Tags: ruby

I want to have my program print an alternate string if the user's input is incorrect five times. The code I'm using below is giving me `` undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) `` referring to `+=` and I'm not sure why.

```
loop do
  input = gets.chomp
  if input =~ /\d/
    #long case statement here
  else
    annoyed += 0
    if annoyed == 5 
      puts "alternate prompt"
    else
      puts "normal prompt"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi. It's probably because `annoyed` is `nil` as the error suggests. What you are looking for is probably increasing annoyed by 1 and of course starting from a value which is probably 0 outside of loop. I can fix your code but its probably better if you figure out yourself ;)

Comment: Ah, I figured out my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@radubogdan, in a comment, has explained the problem with your code. Consider writing it something like the following.

```
wrong_answers = 0

loop do
  print wrong_answers < 5 ?
    "Will you agree to tell me who your handler is?: " :
    "Your life is toast if you don't tell me. Will you tell me now?: "
  if gets.chomp.match?(/yes/i)
    puts "You've come to your senses"
    puts "executing code..."
    break
  end
  puts "You're lying"
  wrong_answers += 1
end
```

The following conversation might take place.

```
Will you agree to tell me who your handler is?: no 
You're lying
Will you agree to tell me who your handler is?: No!
You're lying
Will you agree to tell me who your handler is?: nyet
You're lying
Will you agree to tell me who your handler is?: shove it
You're lying
Will you agree to tell me who your handler is?: never!
You're lying
Your life is toast if you don't tell me. Will you tell me now?: don't hit me again
You're lying
Your life is toast if you don't tell me. Will you tell me now?: #%$ **#
You're lying
Your life is toast if you don't tell me. Will you tell me now?: yes
You've come to your senses
executing code...
```

I wrote `print arg` where:

```
arg = wrong_answers < 5 ? "Will you agree..." : "Your life is toast..."
```

The right side of this expression employs a [ternary operator](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/10/ruby-ternary-operator/).

Comment: This is a good alternative solution. Also great examples. Thanks!